# Spectrum filtering using time lag

Tags: signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

Given a signal in time domain. can i separate its spectrum for a particular frequency AND  containing a particular time lag(or phase).

I have a sample signal and with Nyquist rang of 250 Hz. I just need to select frequency range of 0- to 20 Hz with a time shift of 20 msec.

The Sampling frequency is 500 and sampling rate is 2 msec. Total record length is 6 sec with 3001 samples
thanks

```
fs=500; %sampling freqeuncy
x=testshot3.traces(:,1);% discrete signal 1D.taking out one signal
slen=length(x);
nfft = 2^nextpow2(2*slen); % To use max. computational efficiency of FFT
fax = fs*(-nfft/2:nfft/2-1)'/nfft; % Create frequency shift vectors(bins)

kk=20; %lag to find 20 msec.remeber sample rate is 2 msec. so this would come as 10th sample

FX=fft(x,nfft);%fft of the the 2D signal x
A=abs(FX);%amplidue of x
ff=find(round(fax)>=-20 & round(fax)<=20 );% finding frequency bins  from -20 to 20 Hz
l_ff=length(ff);%length of selected freguency bins

% setting condition for filter: Frequency and lag
for j=1:1: l_ff % rows of frequency range
fx_real=abs(real(fx(ff(j,1),1)));% frequency values  real part 
ee=abs(real(exp(1i*2*pi*fax(ff(j,1),1)))); % exp part

dn=A(ff(j,1),1).*ee; % frequency bin value for real part
lags=fx_real./dn; % find lag
if round(lags)==round(abs(exp(kk*pi)))% condition
FX=0.01*FX(ff(j,1),1);

 end
end

dum = ifft(FX_all); % Return to time domain
filter= real(dum(1:slen,:));
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Scott. Please see the edited post.